# How to test the interstitial ad in mAdserve android SDK

Tags: javascript, android, xml

I already have tested the banner ad in Android sdk through my own server and banner ads displayed normally as I expected.

Is that the XML format response of banner ads the same as the interstitial ads?

I have no clue about that. When I hit "show video/interstitial" button, it just shows "No ad found". I could not find any Javascript interstitial ad code on the mAdserve. Could anybody give some example code so that I can test whether the android sdk could show interstitial ads?